# how to get the value from dropdwon in selectpicker- it alert the value twice?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using select picker . I have one dropdrown where i have get the value when the element is selected. Here is get the value successfully but it alerts me twice time when i remove the selectpicker class it gives me right result. Here is my code:-

```
enter code here
<select class="selectpicker show-tick getCategory" data-size="12">
    <option value="">Category</option>
    <?php foreach ($allcategories as $key => $category) {?>
        <option value="{{ $category['name'] }}">{{ $category['name'] }} </option>
         <?php } ?>
</select>
```

And here is my Jquery Code:-

```
enter code here
var categoryvalue="";
    $('.getCategory').change(function(){
        categoryvalue = $(".getCategory option:selected").text();
        alert(categoryvalue);
    });
```

When i alert the categoryvalue it gives me right result but alert me twice.
Thanks in advance :)
I am using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**: When you refer to a class the change event fires twice. The solution is to reference an id rather than a class.

```js
$('#test').on('changed.bs.select', function(e) {
  categoryvalue = $(".getCategory option:selected").text();
  alert(categoryvalue);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <select id="test" class="foo selectpicker show-tick getCategory" data-size="12">
    <option value="">Category</option>
        <option value="catTest1">catTest1</option>
        <option value="catTest2">catTest2</option>
        <option value="catTest3">catTest3</option>               
        <option value="catTest4">catTest4</option>
        <option value="catTest5">catTest5</option>
        <option value="catTest6">catTest6</option>
        <option value="catTest7">catTest7</option>        
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: still alerts twice :(

Comment: Indeed, I've updated the correct answer with a code snippet.